# Blue Fn + Function keys not working with Lubuntu on my Thinkpad

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, lxde, laptop, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X201 (if the submodel matters, please say so), with Lubuntu 15.10 running on it. I use LXDE for my desktop environment (as the name suggets).

Now, as you may know, Thinkpads have additional functionality available as part of their keyboard, using a combinations of a blue-typeface "Fn" key in combination with several of the F-row keys (e.g. Fn+F2 is Lock the laptop, Fn+F4 is go to sleep mode, Fn+F7 is switch output display options and so on.)

Unfortunately, these key combinations - which worked well with Windows (AFAICR; only 90% sure of that) - and do not work *at all* with Lubuntu. They seem to do nothing.

Why is that? What can I do to get these key combinations recognized?

**Notes:**

- Using the stock distro kernel with no modifications (4.2.0-34-generic).
- The `thinkpad_acpi` module is loaded. The entirety of my loaded modules are:

  ```
  ablk_helper aesni_intel aes_x86_64 ahci arc4 autofs4 binfmt_misc bluetooth bnep btbcm btintel btrtl btusb cfg80211 coretemp crc32_pclmul crct10dif_pclmul cryptd drm drm_kms_helper e1000e gf128mul glue_helper i2c_algo_bit i915 input_leds intel_ips intel_powerclamp iwldvm iwlwifi joydev kvm libahci lp lpc_ich lrw mac80211 mac_hid mei mei_me Module nls_iso8859_1 nvram parport parport_pc ppdev pps_core psmouse ptp serio_raw shpchp snd snd_hda_codec snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_core snd_hda_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_timer soundcore thinkpad_acpi uas usb_storage video wmi
  ```
- I have used my BIOS to switch the positions of Ctrl and Fn (i,e, Ctrl is effectively to bottom-leftmost key and Fn is emitted).

Comment: Did you check if you need a special package to make these keys work? Something like thinkpad_acpi driver? IAs fa as I can remember I needed this driver, but it's a long time ago...

Comment: @mnille: The thinkpad_acpi driver/module is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

These keys have undefined behavior to Lunbuntu/Xorg/LXDE, they worked in windows because your drivers were machine specific, these keys/ key combinations may vary among thinkpads and therefore are not covered by `thinkpad_acpi`

The keys are not identified because either:

- The keycodes are not mapped to any functionality
- The scancodes created by those keystrokes are not mapped to any keycodes

Dealing with all the possibilities in this post would be redundant and lengthy.
You should read this [article about handling extra keys from the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys), the commands will not all translate to Lubuntu, but this should get you in the right direction.

The `showkey` tool should work in a shell session on Lubuntu, but will not work while X, your display server, is running

While X is running you will need `xorg-xev` (part of the x11 utilities package, `sudo apt-get install x11-utils`).

Comment: Cheers for the edits *buntu knowers